# Perl and MYSQL - Select data between year-month-day hour:minute:seconds (unix?) style timestamps

Tags: mysql, perl, date

I have looked all day for an answer and tried all my thoughts as well.
What I am doing is seemingly easy but, VERY difficult for me.
I must do this without installing additional Perl Modules.

I am trying to select a list of names that were entered between two dates.
I know these examples are obviously not strict or safe but, I am just trying to figure out.
I will fix all that later once I get the means to my required result figured out.

The incoming data example for the $to and $from:

```
$to= '2013-03-01 00:00:01';
$from= '2013-03-01 23:23:59';
```

The `entered` column in the database is in that format as well.

I tried:

```
$names = DBI->connect("$sdb","$user","$password");
   $getnames = $names->prepare(qq{SELECT DISTINCT `name` 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE `entered` 
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP($from) 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP($to) 
    AND `active` = ? 
    AND `confirmed` = ? 
    ORDER BY `entered` DESC});
    $getnames->execute($active,$confirmed);
```

And I tried:

```
    $names = DBI->connect("$sdb","$user","$password");
    $getnames = $names->prepare(qq{SELECT DISTINCT `name`
   FROM `users`
   WHERE `entered` BETWEEN ?
   AND ?
   AND `active` = ?
   AND `confirmed` = ?
   ORDER BY `entered` DESC});
   $getnames->execute($from,$to,$active,$confirmed);
```

I also tried many variations of the above two but, I keep getting:

```
Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at users-by-date.pl line 120 even when I hard code the variables.
```

Can someone show me how to do this? My query executes fine in phpmyadmin but, I need the result printed to a page using Perl. I believe it has something to do with the dates format. NO, I cannot change the dates format in the database.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Your error suggests that the connect() call is failing. Are you able to perform any successful queries with Perl DBI?

Comment: @Josh I will double check.

Comment: How does your `$sdb` string look like? Someting like `dbi:mysql:your_database`? As Josh said the connect seems to be failing. Add a `die` and look at the errormessage. (`$names = DBI->connect("$sdb","$user","$password") or die $DBI::errstr;`)

Comment: Yes, that is the first problem. Very strange. Not remote but, localhost as well. In the same directory, I have another script connecting to a remote server with the same code with no problem. This one just cannot connect to its' server! Tried the ip, the domain and localhost to no avail. ($sdb = 'DBI:mysql:root_db1:localhost:3306';) I will get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$names = DBI->connect("$sdb","$user","$password");
```

should be

```
$names = DBI->connect($sdb, $user, $password) or die "Couldn't connect to database: $!";
```

Adding the `or die...` part will serve two purposes:

1) It will stop your program immediately, preventing you from getting spurious errors later when you try to use the database handle, when the real problem is that it failed to connect to the database.

2) It will tell you *why* the database connection failed.  (The database's error message will be in `$!`.)

I also removed the double quotes around the variables because they're not needed.